# Local variables or direct statements?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I am currently studying C# and I really want to get a good coding style from the beginning, so I would like to hear opinions from you professionals on this matter.

Should you always (or mostly) use local variables for conditions/calculations (example 2) or is it just as good/better to use statements directly (example 1)

Example 1.

```
if (double.TryParse(stringToParse, out dblValue)) ...
```

Example 2.

```
bool parseSuccess = double.TryParse(stringToParse, out dblValue);
if (parseSuccess) ...
```

It would be interesting to hear your thoughts and reasoning at this example.

Comment: Do what you are comfortable with, it doesn't make any difference when you run the code.  You'll probably stop using these helper variables when you get more familiar with .NET

Comment: I think this is by and large a personal preference, but normally I would lean toward whatever is most readable, in this case, the latter.  Though I would use var parseSuccess ... personally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the more verbose style if putting it all in one line would make it too long or complicated.

You should also use a separate variable if the variable's name would make it easier to understand the code:

```
bool mustWait = someCommand.ConflictsWith(otherCommand);
if (mustWait) {
    ...
}
```

In such cases, you should consider using an enum for additional readability.

Comment: This is a great example. The question's example of `TryParse` already _tends_ to communicate to the if block to "do this if I parse successfully"; in that sense it's on-the-fence and either style is appropriate. Your example demonstrates that `ConflictsWith` does _not_ denote at all that the calling code must wait.  By assigning it to "mustWait", you immediately communicate that "if the command conflicts, we must wait, and here is the code to wait". If the `ConflictsWith` is placed directly in the if condition, then that meaning is lost. This *is* the appropriate way of coding it your example.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of example 1 in production code. As long as the expression is simple, and it's easy to understand the logic of what's happening, I don't think you'll find many people who think it is *bad style*.

Though you will probably find a lot of people with different preferences. :)

Answer (score 1):

Heres the rule I use: Keep it on one line if you can quickly glance over it and know exactly what it's saying. If its too complicated to read as quickly as you could read any other text, give it a local variable. In any case, though, you don't want a really long if statement header. So if it's too long, split it up.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a local variable like here:

```
bool parseSuccess = double.TryParse(stringToParse, out dblValue);
if (parseSuccess) ...
```

For two reasons:

**1.** You can use more times the variable without parse your double another time.

**2.** It makes the code more readable.

Consider this:

```
if(double.TryParse(string1, out Value1) && double.TryParse(string2, out Value2) && double.TryParse(string3, out Value3) && double.TryParse(string4, out Value4))
{
    //some stuff
}
```

It's too long and it makes the code hard to be read.
So sometimes local variabels make the code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The clarity of the source code is an important parameter especially in application maintenance but so is performance.

Insignificant it may seem, sometimes using simple syntax "tricks" of programming languages​​, we get very good results.

If I think I'll use later in the code somehow the result, I use variables, otherwise I give priority to direct sentences.

Answer (score 0):

There's no right option. Both are perfectly acceptable.

Most people choose the first option if you don't have a lot of conditions to concatenate because it results in less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are studying C#

So my vote will be this style for you

```
bool parseSuccess = double.TryParse(stringToParse, out dblValue);
if (parseSuccess) ...
```

If you are studying you will have lot to learn and the above
style clearly tells you that TryParse return a bool, so you won't have
to worry or find whats the return type for TryParse